# Is it possible to define primaryKey on runtime for Laravel / Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Eloquent, I know it's possible to define the table on runtime with $model->setTable().

I tried adding a new item in the constructor like:

```
$myModel = new \MyModel(array(), 'my_primary_key');
$myModel->setTable('mytable');
```

with the constructor being:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent { 
    public function __construct($attributes = array(), $primaryKey = 'id') {
        parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent
        $this->primaryKey = $primaryKey;
    }
}
```

That makes my $primaryKey = 'id' like the default.
- This one doesn't work cause it doesn't change the primaryKey to whatever I define in my call the constructor, it just gets the default ('id'). If I don't set a default I get the following error:

```
 Missing argument 3 for MyModel::__construct(), called in
 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 517 and defined
```

I also tried:

```
 $myModel->setAttribute('primaryKey', 'my_primary_key');
```

But this one doesn't set the attribute

But nothing works. The default for Laravel is having 'id' as the primaryKey, but in my tables I have things like 'car_id' for table Cars, and so on, so I get errors like:

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' 
 (SQL: select * from `cars`      where `id` = 1 limit 1)
```

I tried to look into the code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1415, but it doesn't have a method to set it on runtime.

Comment: Is this the primary key in your database ?

Comment: What does "nothing works" mean? Error messages?

Comment: I just edited the question :)